# (Discord.js) how too tag the bot itself

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

okay , hey there.

Im trying too ping/tag the bot itself in Discord.js.
soo when a user ping the bot in a command that it replies with an error message i defined myself. 
thats what i have so far :

```
   async run(message, args) 
    {
        let huggeduser = message.mentions.users.first()
        let auser = message.author
            if(huggeduser == message.author) {
                message.channel.send(`${auser} , you cant hug yourself!`)
                return;
                }
            if(client.bot = huggeduser) {  //(Note) How too tag the bot as it self like : (huggeduser == <the string too tag the bot>) {
                message.channel.send("You cant meeeee hug!")
                return;
            }
```

the rest of the code works fine.
just the code-part of the with the (note)

i would love if someone can help me on that. ive been trying it myself for 2 days now.

Thanks.

Comment: in your note and earlier in the same function you use `==` for comparison. so use `==` for comparison

Comment: also it's `client.user` not `client.bot`

Comment: @klaycon , i know but im trying too ping the bot , not the user , and i tried it , and it still dosnt work , sadly. but thanks

Comment: `client.bot` is undefined. `client.user` is the client (your bot)'s logged in user (the bot user). if it's not working, try comparing the IDs instead of the entire objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double equal signs for checking equality. Also, checking the entire user objects is inefficient, just check their IDs.

Additionally, based on your error in the comments, and the name of this function, I'm assuming this is in a different file and you have a line like this at the top:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

So in this context, `client` is *not* your logged-in bot user, it's an empty, not logged in bot that doesn't know who it is. You should get the `client` from the message object:

```
   async run(message, args) 
    {
        let huggeduser = message.mentions.users.first()
        let auser = message.author
        if(!huggeduser) return; //message for if no user was mentioned?
        if(huggeduser.id == auser.id) {
            message.channel.send(`${auser} , you cant hug yourself!`)
            return;
        } else if(huggeduser.id == message.client.user.id) {
            message.channel.send("You cant meeeee hug!")
            return;
        }
        //rest of code
```

Comment: `An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
it gave me back as i tried too run it.

Comment: yes i have a `const client = require('discord.js')` , idk about this one , because my friend added it last time , and its like the only file thats using it. i tried too remove it , but then the command itself didnt work at all anymore.

Comment: @Dusty the code I've provided in this answer should work perfectly fine as-is. discord.js exposes the client that received the message on `message.client`, as such, you don't need to declare your own.

Comment: `const client = require('discord.js')` is all sorts of wrong, as `require('discord.js')` is not a client, not even close. it's the Discord object exposing all of discord.js's modules

Comment: but as i deleted it , it the howl section just shutdown and the bot itself just returend error messages , as i tried too excecute it

Comment: @Dusty reading the error messages is likely to give a clue as to why that piece of bad code was apparently essential. perhaps it was being used "correctly" despite being named something as misleading as `client`, in which case you should refactor the name to `Discord` as recommended by discord.js guides

Comment: regardless, that line of code is actually totally, completely irrelevant to the question. the answer to your question is this: `if(huggeduser.id == message.client.user.id) {` and does not depend on whatever else you have going on

Comment: Yes , but like I told you , it keeps saying the same error Message , as I try too execute it.

Comment: please share the updated code and error message in your question

Comment: it works now , i replaced `client`with something else ,and added the `.id` huggeduser and added `message.client.user.id` and it works now , thanks alot